# Casting from string to dynamic types?

Tags: java

I am trying to create object dynamically from csv file. I have get to this part:

Assuming I have this class:

```
package com.example
public TestClass {
    public int hi = 0;
    public String ho = "ho";
}
```

I also have this csv:

```
hi,ho
1,"hello"
```

In the codes below, classIdentifier is a string of the class name (i.e. "com.example.TestClass"), and maps is a HashMap that stores the data read from the csv file.

```
    Class<T> c = (Class<T>) classIdentifier.getClass();
    Set<String> keys = maps.keySet(); 
    for(String key : keys) {
        System.out.println(classIdentifier, c.getDeclaredField(key).getType());
        System.out.println(maps.get(key));
        c.getDeclaredField(key).set(classIdentifier, c.getDeclaredField(key).getType().cast(maps.get(key)));
    }
```

The above code will printout expected values:
int
1

However this will throw the following error in the cast part:
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to int

Although in the given example, hi is int and ho is string, I do want to extend the usage of this code to be able to convert with any type. That means I have no prior knowledge of the fields' type until I use the c.getDeclaredField(key).getType() (That's what I mean by dynamic).

I am just wondering how can I fix it?

Comment: You'd need to realize that you're trying to set to an `int` field, and use `Integer.parseInt` or something similar to parse the string to an integer before setting the field value - just as you would if you were trying to assign a value to the field in normal code.

Comment: @JonSkeet well yes in the example it is a int and string. However "dynamic" means the knowledge of the types comes in only at runtime - and that can extend the same code to convert everything from csv to objects given at runtime. Checking if that is an int and cast to int is not the best approach I think.

Comment: String != int even if a String contains an integer. If you want a dynamic version of Java try Groovy

Comment: Well, I hate to suggest this, but you could cast the CSV into JSON as `{"hi":1, "ho":"hello"}`, then use Jackson to init your class.

Comment: @jamesdeath123: You can think it's not the best approach, but *something* is going to have to look at the type of the field and perform the conversion...

Comment: @JonSkeet I have decided to include a string representing the class name in the method, which makes it possible to instantiate class instances.

Comment: @jamesdeath123: I don't see that the class name was the problem at all - it was the *field type* that was the issue, wasn't it? And you can check that using the `Field` you get from `c.getDeclaredField`.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, I was confused. I may need to have a factory class to deal with that